# Decreasing complexity of loop & Find- VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code; both Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are rather big sheet with lots of data. Run this Macro is extremely time comsuming ( It has a high complexity I guess). I'm quite new at VBA and therefore having trouble make the code more effective.

```
Sub Find()

    Dim rgFound As Range
    Dim Index As Long: Index = 6
    Dim Row as Long

    Do While Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Index, "D").Value > 0

         Sheets("Sheet1").Select
         Set rgFound = Range("A1:A20000").Find(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Index, "D").Value)

         If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then

            Row = rgFound.Row

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AA" & Index).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AB" & Index).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AC" & Index).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Z" & Index).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AG" & Index).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AD" & Index).Value

        Else
            ' Function // Not done yet
        End If

    Index = Index + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Is the built in `Find` function effective? The loop loops trough roughly 250-400 values. Any Ideas?

Comment: get rid of  `Sheets("Sheet1").Select` and just reference the sheet directly: `Set rgFound = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20000")...`

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about the data that being stored and looked up? Perhaps using a different data structure, like a dictionary would be a better fit.

Comment: If the code works as intended, you can get a thorough peer review with feedback on any/all aspects of the code on [codereview.se].